# Looping through a list in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create 3 different .png images in R and save them to 3 different files - all at once.

The following code creates 1 image and then stops.  Why not the other 2 images?

**“MatrixFunction”** is my own function that requires a df, column numbers, title.  Each test type is also the name of a data frame.

Thank you.

```
testtype <- list("Grade4TopBottom", "Grade8TopBottom", "HSPATopBottom")

for(i in testtype){

    mypath <- paste("testing", testtype)
    png(mypath, width=1336, height=656)
    MatrixFunction(get(i), 8:19, "Title")
    dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your file over and over again. There's an obvious typo: `mypath <- paste("testing", i)`. In that case, you will create tree separate files instead of one.

Comment: Oh, Thank you!  I do require 3 separate files, so this works.  Out of curiosity, how would I put all 3 files in 1 file, with 3 separate pages?

Comment: If you want 1 image with 3 plots on it, see `?par`, `mfrow`, `mfcol`. Otherwise, I am not sure what you mean by pages.

Comment: png images do not support pages. For this, you will have to use pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `for`-loops in `R`. They are notorious slow.

If you create your method as a function, it is easier to check for errors and you can apply `lapply` or `sapply` to it,

```
testtype <- list("Grade4TopBottom", "Grade8TopBottom", "HSPATopBottom")
make.image <- function(n) {    
    obj <- mget(n, ifnotfound=NA)[[1]]
    if (is.na(obj)) return(FALSE)
    mypath <- paste("testing", n)
    png(mypath, width=1336, height=656)
    MatrixFunction(obj, 8:19, "Title")
    dev.off()
    return(TRUE)
}
# test:
make.image('Grade4TopBottom')  # should return TRUE
make.image('Nope')             # should return FALSE
sapply(testtype, make.image)
```